# PHP mysqli query searching for backslashes

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

I have an SQL query which searches for json strings, these json strings include backslashes within them to escape quotation marks.

The SQL query I am using works to find what I am looking for but I'm struggling to get a PHP mysqli query working due to having to have backslashes within the query which are literal and not escape characters, but also having to use backslashes to escape quotation marks within the mysqli query.

So the string I'm searching for is this, with the backslashes actually appearing within the string:

> [insert=\"userform\",id=\"1\"]

The SQL query I use is:

```
SELECT id, name FROM `posts` WHERE content LIKE '%[insert=\\"userform\\",id=\\"1\\"]%' ESCAPE "|"
```

This works to find the rows I want by changing the default excape character. But then when I try to use the same query in PHP I have to escape the single quotes around the LIKE statement causing issues.

```
$mysqli->query('SELECT id, name FROM `posts` WHERE content LIKE \'%[insert=\\"userform\\",id=\\"1\\"]%\' ESCAPE "|"');
```

I'm trying to use mysqli_real_escape_string as I think that will do what I need, but haven't been able to get it right yet, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: by the way, if you need a query like this, your database likely needs a redesign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because php escape character is backslash, you need to escape them too like.

```
$mysqli->query('SELECT id, name FROM `posts` WHERE content LIKE \'%[insert=\\\\"userform\\\\",id=\\\\"1\\\\"]%\' ESCAPE "|"');
```

A good solution to check it's to echo the query before execute to check if the final result is good.